# What do I use for the lifetime of a parameter of an FnMut field inside a struct?

Tags: rust

I have the following code:

```
struct Callable<P> {
    callable: Box<FnMut(&P)>,
}

struct Parameters<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
}

struct Context<'a> {
    call: Callable<Parameters<'a>>,
}
```

`Callable` is something that can be called with a reference to a parameter of type `P`.

`Parameters` contains a reference to a string, so it makes total sense that it has a generic lifetime parameter. It basically says that the `text` field should live at least as long as the `Parameters` itself.

I have to add a generic lifetime parameter for `Context` too, otherwise there is nothing I can use for the `call` member type. This doesn't make any sense to me, as the `'a` parameter has nothing to do with the lifetime of `Context`.

I suspect that the `for <'a>` construct can be used somehow, I just can't figure out where to put it.

Comment: *It basically says that the `text` field should live at least as long as the `Parameters` itself.* — that is not what the lifetime means, although it is true that the reference has to outlive the struct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`for<'a>` can only be used in trait bounds and trait objects; `Parameters<'a>` is not a trait.

The solution is a feature that is currently in development: *generic associated types*. Generic associated types can be thought of as functions operating on types (i.e. given one or many types/lifetimes, produce another type). Your program would look like this:

```
#![feature(generic_associated_types)]

trait CallableParameterFamily {
    type Type<'a>;
}

struct Callable<P>
where
    P: CallableParameterFamily,
{
    callable: Box<for<'a> FnMut(&P::Type<'a>)>,
}

struct Parameters<'a> {
    text: &'a str,
}

enum ParametersFamily {}
impl CallableParameterFamily for ParametersFamily {
    type Type<'a> = Parameters<'a>; // given 'a, produce Parameters<'a>
}

struct Context {
    call: Callable<ParametersFamily>,
}
```

(As of Rust 1.25.0-nightly (2018-02-14 `3ec5a99aaa0084d97a9e845b34fdf03d1462c475`), the feature appears to be partially implemented, and the code above doesn't work, so I can't verify if it's correct or if I made a mistake here.)

The key here is that we don't want a `Callable<Parameters<'a>>` with a specific lifetime `'a`, because we might want to call the closure with different lifetimes for `'a` each time. We can't pass a type constructor (such as `Parameters`) as a type parameter to a generic type (such as `P` on `Callable`).

Generic associated types will allow that, in an indirect way: we have to define a trait with a generic associated type (here, `CallableParameterFamily` with the GAT `Type`) along with a type that implements that trait (here, `ParametersFamily`). Notice that `ParametersFamily` has no lifetime parameter. We then use `Callable<ParametersFamily>` as the type for the `call` field in `Context`; `Context` no longer needs a lifetime parameter. Then, in `Callable`, instead of using `P` directly, we use `P::Type<'a>` after introducing `'a` using `for<'a>`. When instantiated as `Callable<ParametersFamily>`, `P::Type<'a>` will expand to `Parameters<'a>`, which is what we wanted.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! What you said makes sense, although I wish it could have been handled by Rust in a less verbose way.
I just started learning Rust, and the farther I go, the more I feel that Rust's explicit handling of lifetimes via generics is a drawback, not an advantage. It takes just too much effort to state the obvious.